Why does an object kept at focus never form an image? (Concave Mirror)
I have read that when an object is kept at focus of a concave mirror, the rays of light reflected by the object never meet even after reflection from the concave mirror. I don't seem to understand that.

In this diagram, if C is really the center of the circle of which the mirror arc is a part of, then AD will always be smaller than FP since A will be always above F but D will be behind P. However CF will be equal to FP and therefore bigger than AD. ∠EAD will be equal to ∠ACF because AD and CF are parallel.
Here's the question:
If two lines at equal angles(AD and CF) between two rays(ray X and ray Y) are unequal, how can the rays be parallel? If no, then why don't the rays appear to meet and form a virtual image.
PS: I know there are proofs that can prove that image is formed at infinity but I want to know the issue with my reasoning and where it breaks apart.


If two lines at equal angles ($AD$ and $CF$) between two rays (ray $X$ and ray $Y$) are unequal, how can the rays be parallel?

Geometrically, it can't be parallel. As the below diagram shows, according to the law of reflection of light rays (i.e. $\angle CDH=\theta$), we can obtain that $\angle DHP = 2\theta$. To let line $CA$ be parallel to line $HD$, the angle $\angle CAP$ and angle $\angle DHP$ should be equal. But this can't be reached, because the length of segment $AC$ and segment $AD$ can't be equal. (Unless point $D$ coincides with point $P$.)


Then why don't the rays appear to meet and form a virtual image.

These two rays will indeed meet at some point, but this single condition is not sufficient to form an image,  let alone for forming a virtual image.
When we say 'forming the real/virtual image', we are considering the situation that the light source is composed of countless light rays (for example, the below figure (b) and (c)), rather than just two rays (for example, the below figure (a)).
To form an 'image', the key is to have enough much rays converge near a single point. When a point light source is placed on the focal plane (e.g. place it on the point $A$), about <50% of the rays will intersect with the extension of ray $CA$, but the intersection points vary greatly... i.e. they do not converge near the same single point. Some points are very close to each other, while others are far apart.

Whether an 'observable image' can be formed defends on the relative distance between the point source and the optical axis. 
When the point source $A$ is close to the optical axis, it's hard to observe its virtual image. $\downarrow$

When the point source $A$ is far from the optical axis, it's possible to observe its virtual image. $\downarrow$

This is actually quite understandable. When point source $A$ is far away from one optical axis, it is equivalent to being closer to another optical axis. But when taking the optical axis 2 as the reference, the point source $A$ is no longer located on the focal plane. (N.B. when the distance between object and the concave mirror is less than the focal length, it will form an virtual image.)


I will use the mirror formula for the proof(you will find the proof on the internet)
The formula is : $$\frac{1}{f}= \frac{1}{u}+ \frac{1}{v}$$
$f$ is the focal length
$u$ is the distance of object from the pole
$v$ is the distance of image from the pole
Now using the sign convention which says that distances measured in the direction of the light rays are positive and distances measured in the direction opposite to the light rays is taken negative.
if we take the radius vector from pole to focus, the radius vector points against the incident light rays so the focal length is to be taken $-f$ in case of a concave mirror. (Imagine the radius vector as an arrow pointing from the pole to the object)
Now as the image is kept at focus, $u=-f$.
plugging all this in the equation it comes
$$\frac{1}{-f} = \frac{1}{-f} + \frac{1}{v}$$
So
$$-\frac{1}{f} = -\frac{1}{f} + \frac{1}{v}$$
And moving the inverse f term to another side;
$$-\frac{1}{f}+\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{v}$$
And hence,
$$\frac{1}{v}=0$$
And so,
$$v = \infty$$
This implies that the image is formed at infinity. And hence no image is formed and so the light rays are parallel to each other.
I hope this solves your doubt!!!

That is all well and good, but I want to know the problem with the reasoning going on in my head as provided in the question. Because that leads me to believe something else.
